# IP to DNS in DataGridView populated from MSSQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have a simple form that populates a datagridview from a sql query as below:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var select = "SELECT  top(10) CAST(CAST(substring([nSrcIPAddress], 1, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) + '.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nSrcIPAddress], 2, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) +'.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nSrcIPAddress], 3, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) +'.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nSrcIPAddress], 4, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) AS Source,CAST(CAST(substring([nDstIPAddress], 1, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) + '.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nDstIPAddress], 2, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) +'.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nDstIPAddress], 3, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) +'.' + CAST(CAST(substring([nDstIPAddress], 4, 1) AS int) AS nvarchar(3)) AS Destination, round(sum([nBytes])/1048576.0,2) AS MB FROM Source INNER JOIN SourceInterfaceMap ON Source.nSourceID = SourceInterfaceMap.nSourceID INNER JOIN FlowRaw ON SourceInterfaceMap.nInterfaceID = FlowRaw.nInputInterfaceID where sName = '" + cmbSwitch.Text + "' and (dTime > DATEADD(minute, -" + cmbPeriod.Text + ", getdate())) group by nSrcIPAddress,nDstIPAddress order by sum(nBytes) desc";
        var c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQL; Database=Net; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    //dns here
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostEntry(item.ToString()).HostName);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }                        
                }
            }

            dgvResults.ReadOnly = true;
            dgvResults.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
```

datagridview once populated looks like:

```
Source          Destination MB
40.102.130.1    10.10.1.1   112.2
10.70.1.22      10.3.3.2    58.8
```

what i am trying to do is either lookup the ip and return hostname before i populate the datagrid or loop through the datagrid column 1 and 2 and read value and replace with dns name if available?

Comment: Take a look at [GetHostEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example,

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("IP", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("127.0.0.1");
table.Rows.Add("10.70.1.22");
// generated a table at runtime to create issue quickly.

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) // itterate over rows
{
    try
    {
       IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(row["IP"].ToString()); // Try get host entry inside loop
       row["IP"] = entry.HostName; // if GetHostEntry find HostName set it to row
    }
    catch(Exception) // if GetHostEntry can't find hostname it will throw error but i removed throw to not terminate the program
    {
    }      
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = table; // set as source
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Works a treat, Thanks